# Applying condition on parameters in SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am calculating a column based on existing `tables` column, but I don't know how to do that.

To explain my problem, let's say I have a table which has two columns A and B, both are int. What I am doing right now is

```
Select A,B (A-B)as C from Table
```

The check I want to apply is

> if C is less then Zero it should show Zero. rather then a negative
> value.

What is the way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select A,B,
CASE WHEN (A-B) < 0 THEN 0
ELSE (A-B)
END as C 
from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  Select A,B ,case when(A-B)< 0 then 0 else (A-B) end as C from Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to Use **[CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)**

This is what you want:

```
select A,B,
case when(A-B) < 0 then 0 else (A-B) end as c 
from Table
```

### Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b7e3/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

```
    try this

    select a,b,(a-b < 0 , 0 , a-b) as c from <table>
    // if then usage in mysql

    SELECT a,b,if(a-b < 0;0;a-b) as c FROM <table>
    // if then usage in sql

    // ie. if a-b is less than 0 then 0 else a-b
```

Comment: FYI - the question is tagged with SQL Server, and specifically Transact-SQL.  That uses `CASE` statements, rather than if-then.